# Invariance of Sufficient Statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am doing an online stats course and I had a question about sufficiency. Essentially, I am wondering if I calculate a minimally sufficient statistic, lets say for parameter *p* of Bin(n,p), would this also be a minimally sufficient statistic for a function of such as $p^2$.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It will be a sufficient statistic for a function of the parameter.  It will be minimally sufficient for an injective $1-1$ function (as in your example here of $p^2$, since $p \in [0,1]$ being a binomial parameter) but not necessarily for all functions